# protected configurarion in dotnet core 3

Tags: c#, .net, database, rsaprotectedconfiguration

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and wish to include this in a project I'm working on. Of course, I could just place the connection string with all the data in the C# program itself, but I wish to do it more secure if possible. I have looked at protected configuration and I'm using the following code from Microsoft: [RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). But when I try to encrypt app.config I get an exception at `config.save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);` with the following message `Inner exception ConfigurationErrorsException: Invalid key value.`

This is the app.config I use:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="database" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=database;User Id=username;Password=test"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

To make sure that I have the proper right to encrypt the section I run the application with administrator rights by using the following code in app.manifest: `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

So my question is how can I protect the configuration and how can I access the configuration to make the connection with the database?